# Using Controller.File() method hangs Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firefox

I am using the built-in File() method on the controller class to return a file like so:

```
return File(fileByteArray, "application/octet-stream", filename);
```

On the actual page itself, the way to download the file is a simple link generated with Html.ActionLink() to the specific action to download the file.

This works fine, and the user is able to download the file, however, after the user has dismissed the Firefox open file dialog, the blue circular Firefox throbber continues to spin and never goes away! This means that the user can't do anything on the page and needs to reload the page by clicking on the reload button next to the address bar (because F5 keystrokes are blocked as well).

Comment: Just tried to reproduce this in a fresh MVC solution and could not. Looks like it's something else that my company's code is doing on the client-side that is making this happen.

Comment: Figured out that is definitely is something that my company's code was doing. Because we use so much ajax, they wanted to display the throbber anytime that a <a> tag was clicked. However this does not work well with downloading files as you are never redirected to another page (which resets the throbber).